# Do the effects of spells that change attitude stack?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, stacking

Do the effects of spells that change the target's attitude stack?

For example, if I use *charm person* on someone, then use [*telempathic projection*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telempathic-projection/), would that set their attitude to helpful?

If it was instead *charm animal*, followed by *telempathic projection*, would that make them a viable target for [*carry companion*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/carry-companion/)?

Comment: Why do you think you'd need telempathic projection on top of charm animal to cast carry companion on them? Charm causes them to treat you as 'friendly' and carry companion requires a friendly animal or magical beast. Seems like telmpathic projection is an unnecessary second step.

Comment: "You touch an animal or magical beast that has a helpful attitude" - Charm sets it to friendly, not to helpful. They are different attitudes on the diplomacy scale.

Comment: I somehow read it as friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They would be friendly unless Telempathic Projection would cause them to be helpful

...but Charm will last much longer, and still last even when telempathic projection ends.

All magic affects targets in at their 'base level' (not a game term, but what works in my head). Magic does not build on other magic unless it explicitly says so. Per the rules on [Stacking Effects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Stacking_Effects)

> **Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths**
> In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one with the highest strength applies.

> **Same Effect with Differing Results**
> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.

> **One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant**
> Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. Both spells are still active, but one has rendered the other useless in some fashion.

Either Charm or T.P. will have a greater strength at accomplishing the same thing (temporarily altering the target's attitude toward you). Regardless of which spell it is, both will be 'in effect' for their duration. In the case where they would both make the target Friendly, then the last spell is 'officially' active, if that becomes important.

---

These two spells, used together on a creature that wasn't already Friendly, would not allow you to use Carry Companion on them.

Comment: Carry companion specifically requires them to be helpful, while charm animal only puts them to friendly state. As per diplomacy those are different levels.